# Count consecutive 1

Tags: python

I have an assignment where I am to count the occurrences of consecutive 1:s in a sequence. This is where I'm at. Why doesn't this work?

```
def count11(seq):
    x = 0
    for i in seq:
        if i == 1:
            if seq[i+1] == 1:
                x += 1
    return x

print(count11([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]))
```

Edit: The function is supposed to count the number of pairs of ones, so the given sequence should output 2.

Comment: `i` is a *value* in `seq` (`for i in seq`) but you are *also* trying to use it as an *index*: `if seq[i+1] == 1:`

Comment: the for loop, you may want to use range. for index in range(0, len(seq) -1):

Comment: What if you have `[0,1,1,0,1,1]` What should be the output? 2 or 4? And for the example you have, do you expect the answer to be 3 or 1?

Comment: You can set the flag to True when you find the first 1 and any consecutive 1s will have the flag set to True. When you flip the flag to True, reset the counter to 1. If the count > 1 and flag is True, you know there is are consecutive 1s. That will help you detect consecutive 1s

Comment: Joe, the output in that sequence would be 2. Same as in my sequence, the function is supposed to count pairs. Sorry that I wasn't more clear.

Comment: My response should address it. I also see that you have ypdated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code Review and fix

First let's review your code:

```
for i in seq
```

The for loop will get you each element from the sequence. So this will be values of 0s and 1s.

Inside the loop, you are checking

```
if seq[i+1] == 1:
```

Since the values of `i` can be only 0 or 1, you are checking through the loop for values of `seq[1]` or `seq[2]` depending on the value of `i` in the list `seq`. Instead, you should iterate through the list for the length of `seq` - 1 times (since python list index starts from `0`).

To do that, you can set the counter to 0 and for every iteration inside the for loop, increment the counter by 1 and use that to check `seq`. Python makes it easy by having `enumerate(seq)`. This will give you a tuple `(counter, value)`. That way you have direct access to the counter and can use that to check the counter + 1 value as well. Or you can iterate through the loop using range (0 to len of seq - 1).

Your modified code will be as follows:

```
def count11(seq):
    x = 0
    for i in range (len(seq)-1):
        if seq[i] == seq[i+1] == 1: #check if ith and i+1th position are both equal to 1
            x += 1
    return x
```

For a value of `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]`, the result will be `2`

## Alternate solutions:

There are three types of consecutive checks we can do. I am going to give you code for all 3 types.

Type 1: If the value is `[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]`, there are two sequence of 1s in this list. So the result can be 2.

Type 2: An alternate way to look at this is to find any two elements and if they are both 1s, then count it as sequence. If that's the case, the result will be 3 (1, 1 for first and second, then 1, 1 for second and third, then 1, 1 for last two elements).

Type 3: Another check you can do is to find the highest sequence of 1s in a list. In this case, the highest will be 3.

In the below code,

`consec_a` function will result in 3 (check if the next element is also a 1). This solution is similar to what you have. I have made it a list comprehension and a single line.

`consec_b` function will result in 2 (check if there is a series of uninterrupted 1s)

`consec_c` function will check for 3 (find the max number of uninterrupted 1s)

```
def consec_a(sequ):
    return sum(sequ[i] == sequ[i+1] == 1 for i in range(len(sequ)-1))

def consec_b(sequ):
    seq_flag = False
    seq_count = 0
    for i in range (len(sequ)-1):
        if sequ[i] == sequ[i+1] == 1:
            if not seq_flag: seq_count += 1
            seq_flag = True
        else: seq_flag = False
    return seq_count

def consec_c(sequ):
    seq_flag = False
    seq_count = 1
    max_count = 0
    for i in range (len(sequ)-1):
        if sequ[i] == sequ[i+1] == 1:
            seq_count += 1
            if max_count < seq_count: max_count = seq_count
            seq_flag = True
        else:
            seq_flag = False
            seq_count = 1
    return max_count

print ('Results of consec_a function :')
print('[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]', consec_a([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]))

print('[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]', consec_a([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]))

print('[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]', consec_a([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]))

print('[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]', consec_a([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))

print('[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', consec_a([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))

print ('\nResults of consec_b function :')
print('[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]', consec_b([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]))

print('[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]', consec_b([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]))

print('[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]', consec_b([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]))

print('[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]', consec_b([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))

print('[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', consec_b([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))

print ('\nResults of consec_c function :')
print('[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]', consec_c([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]))

print('[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]', consec_c([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]))

print('[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]', consec_c([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]))

print('[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]', consec_c([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))

print('[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', consec_c([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
```

The output of this will be:

```
Results of consec_a function :
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] 2
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1] 2
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1] 3
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 0

Results of consec_b function :
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] 1
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1] 2
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1] 2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 1
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 0

Results of consec_c function :
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] 3
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1] 2
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1] 3
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 6
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 0
```

Hopefully the code is easy to understand. If you need clarification, let me know.

I am using chaining to check for 1s.

```
if sequ[i] == sequ[i+1] == 1
```

This checks if all the values are equal to 1 and if yes, then the equation is set to True

```
sum(sequ[i] == sequ[i+1] == 1 .....)
```

This sums all the True values. As you know True = 1 and False = 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a one-liner:

```
import re
import math

def count(seq):
    return math.ceil(len(max(re.sub(r"[^1]"," ","".join(map(str, seq))).split(), key=len))/2)

print (count([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]))
```

This returns the max number of pairs (longest repeat / 2 round up), two (overlapping) pairs in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use `i` as your index, which is the current item in the sequence, and not its index. At that point, `i` is always 1, because you checked it before. A way to solve it would be using `emumerate`, which gives you a tuple with the current item itself and its index.

```py
for idx, item in enumerate(seq):
    # idx is the index, item is 1 or 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a similar question and variations to it for practice [LeetCode - Max Consecutive Ones](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-consecutive-ones/)

Below was my solution for it

Intuition of the solution -

- Maintain c(counter) to track the current run of 1s. Update the max_run after increment of cnt.
- Reset c(counter) to 0 when we encounter 0 in the array.

```
def findMaxConsecutiveOnes(nums):
    n = len(nums)
    if n == 1 and nums[0] == 1:
       return 1
    
    res = 0
    c = 0
    
    for i in range(n):
        if nums[i] == 1:
           c += 1
           res = max(c,res)
        else:
           c = 0 
    return res

>>> findMaxConsecutiveOnes([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
3
```

Answer (score 0):

the `i` in your code is the item in seq, not the index of seq. you can get the first consecutive 1s through the following codes:

```
def count11(seq):
    count = 0
    for item in seq:
        if not item and count == 0:
            continue
        elif item == 1:
            count += 1
        else:
            break

    return count
```

if you want to get the max consecutive 1s:

```
def count11(seq):
    if not seq:
        return 0
    count = 0
    max_count = 0
    for item in seq:
        if item == 1:
            count += 1
            max_count = max(max_count, count)
        else:
            count = 0
    return max_count
```